# IE 9 request with no method with empty response

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, httprequest

It is a very strange browser issue that my user is encountering. My company site has been working for some years. A month ago there was a user reporting he cannot load our website. What he saw was simply a blank page. The user was kind enough to open the Internet Explorer developer tool to capture the network traffic, and send us the result (a xml file).

We found the following strange request in the xml file: a request with no parameter but a url, and the response is completely empty. Because of this key javascript file was not downloaded, the client see a blank page.

```
<entry>
                <pageref>0</pageref>
                <startedDateTime>2015-04-17T14:51:20.852+08:00</startedDateTime>
                <time>6739</time>
                <request>
                                <method/>
                                <url>http://myhostname.com/page/mykey.js</url>
                                <httpVersion/>
                                <cookies/>
                                <headers/>
                                <queryString/>
                                <headersSize>0</headersSize>
                                <bodySize>0</bodySize>
                </request>
                <response>
                                <cookies/>
                                <headers/>
                                <content>
                                                <size>0</size>
                                                <mimeType/>
                                </content>
                                <redirectionURL/>
                                <headersSize>0</headersSize>
                                <bodySize>0</bodySize>
                </response>
                <cache/>
                <timings>
                                <send>6739</send>
                                <wait>-1</wait>
                                <receive>-1</receive>
                </timings>
</entry>
```

Except the URL in the request, I did not modify anything in the above xml snippet. And this is the only problematic request that we found in the xml file, other requests/responses look normal. The client refreshed the page but Internet Explorer still cannot load this javascript file.

My question is, under what circumstance will IE fire such a strange request? Could it be related to cache issue? e.g. IE somehow cache the wrong file?

Comment: have you tried hitting that url manually in IE and other browsers?

Comment: from the apache log we can see there were some normal request (with the same URL) coming in, and the apache is responding normally. there are also other clients who can successfully log in so I presume this url works normal for other client

Comment: Could you ask the client for the console output? Could be a Javascript problem that is generating some problem and IE just said that is a Network Error. Happens to me before that was Js problem, the process stop and IE said It was some file that could not be loaded.

Comment: long time this has been open, but : looking at the request it seems the method is empty. That is strange, it should contains something like GET or POST, but never be empty. Also, normally there should be a referer that indicates which is the origin of the request.

Comment: we need to see your failing request code

Answer (score 0):

Try these options:

1. Enable/disable GPU acceleration
2. Validate your HTML page, via an HTML validator
3. Have you used multiple ID's with the same name?
4. Maybe there's a problem in Windows's font cache?
5. Check if it works on Chrome?